# create column name suffix with _id without parent table in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

As part of upgrading my rails application to rails 4 I executed the command `rake db:migrate` and it failed since I used the column name with id (supply_ref_id). I know rails will refer the parent table since I used `_id` in suffix. But, It was working in rails <4 applications.

any suggestion to make it work. thx.

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "supply_refs" does not exist
...
...
CONSTRAINT fk_users_supply_ref_id FOREIGN KEY ("supply_ref_id")
REFERENCES "supply_refs" ("id")) /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@demo/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/
database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails does not care about the "_id" suffix for "foreign key" column names, unless you define an association e.g `belongs_to: supply_ref`. And even this association can be configured to use another name for the "foreign key" column as implied by "_id" convention.

I've quickly implemented your example and ain't got any errors:

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :type
      t.integer :supply_ref_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


Foo.create(name: 'foo', supply_ref_id: 4711)
 => #<Foo id: 1, name: "foo", type: nil, supply_ref_id: 4711, created_at: "2015-02-12 09:11:01", updated_at: "2015-02-12 09:11:01">
```

What the error ist actually saying is, that there is some FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT defined (or that rails tries to define it) within your postgres database. It is referencing the `supply_refs` table which does not exist.

Rails actually does not define foreign key constrainst by default. See [3.6 Foreign Keys](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys). So they either have been defined within a migration or some other 3d party gem, like `foreigner`.

You should remove this foreign key definition, if you don't have the `supply_refs` table.

Comment: I have the same issue, but i dont use 'foreigner" gem, and I dont know which gem does it.  Is there way around this? Because rake db:migrate keep failing as it tries to create foreign key contraint.

Comment: Grep your migration code for 'add_foreign_key' It's a default migration method now, as you can see in the doc a linked to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do not have [schema_plus](https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_plus) in your dependency tree.

If so, this solves your problem.

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :type
      t.integer :supply_ref_id, foreign_key: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```